# Is it Possible to get data for "adClicks" metric across the dimension "adPlacementDomain" in Analytics API Reporting?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using Analytics API Reporting V4 and trying to fetch data for the metric "adClicks", I am able to get data across domains like "Campaigns" but for domain "ga:adPlacementDomain" I get no data for clicks.

The point worth mentioning here is that, one can see data in Google Analytic's Console for same settings.

To be sure whether Google Analytics support adClicks with adPlacementDomain, i referred this part of their documentation, 
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

and it seems like this combination is indeed legit.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine this metric and dimension, as they do not get grayed out when selected:

[image]